# Zurb Foundation Sticky Issue: Stops working if I add a bottom anchor

Tags: zurb-foundation, sticky

I am trying to implement the [Advanced](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#advanced) method of using sticky within a Zurb Foundation 6.4.3 one page website.  All my components are up to date.

Things work fine until I add the instructed data-btm-anchor code: if I add that (and no matter what ID I target on my page nor whether I target it's :top or :bottom), sticky stops working (nothing sticks).

Anyone else having issue with using data-btm-anchor?  It seems so straightforward and yet doesn't work for me.

GOAL:  The left and right 3 columns each contain a decorative polygon that acts as a border to the center 18 columns (I use a 24 column grid); the center 18 contains my text.  The overall section has a fixed height (say, 60vh, though in reality the actual dimension adjusts per breakpoint) and overflow-y set to scroll. The idea is that the bordering polygons sit still while the center text area scrolls until we get to the end of that text area, at which point sticky releases and the entire page continues scrolling.  Should be simple, right?

Below is my HTML.  Ignore the actual content (the text), as it is placeholder only; it's the divs and related that matter.  I'll start with the row (div) above what I want to make sticky, as it is the data-top-anchor; the div below what I want to make sticky has an ID of services.  Again, I tried using as my data-btm-anchor="services:top" and also tried data-btm-anchor="slantsText:bottom"; also tried, just to test, using my footer's ID.  Not matter what ID I put in as my data-btm-anchor, sticky stopped working.

NOTE:  My final closing div keeps getting dropped from what I'm pasting below.  In my actual code, all closing divs ARE present (2 after where I note "close slants").

```
<div id="cta">
      <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-x align-center">
              <div class="small-20 medium-16 cell">
                  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x bodyRow">
                      <div class="small-24 cell">
                        <h2>Sign with IHI</h2>
                        <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and  retail space needs <br class="show-for-medium">and our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <div class="text-center">
                              <div id="schedule">
                                  <h6><a href="#/" class="secondary button btnStroked bPr" data-toggle="nPr" aria-controls="nPr">Schedule Your Meeting</a></h6>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!--close cta-->
<div data-sticky-container>
   <div data-sticky data-margin-top="0" data-top-anchor="cta:bottom" data-btm-anchor="services:top">
  <div id="slants">
      <div class="grid-x align-center">
          <div class="small-3 medium-4 cell slantPolyL"></div>
          <div class="small-18 medium-16 cell slantsTextContainer">
              <div class="grid-container">
                  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x bodyRow align-center">
                      <div id="slantsText" class="small-23 medium-18 cell">
                          <h2>Sign with IHI</h2>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                          <p>Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.  Let’s talk about your industrial and/or retail space needs in light of our local markets that&nbsp;await&nbsp;you.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="small-3 medium-4 cell slantPolyR"></div>
      </div>
   </div><!--close slants-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the oddest thing:  If I add an ID to one of the cells within id="services", it works!  For instance, if I use on my data-sticky data-btm-anchor="test:top" then, within my id="services" add an id="test", that id works (whereas, again, data-btm-anchor="services:top" does not):

```
<!--reopen contained grid container-->
<div id="services" class="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x bodyRow2 align-center">
        <div id="test" class="small-8 medium-6 large-4 cell redEmphH"></div>
    </div>
```

Does the ID need to be on a cell, not, for instance, on the div with class="grid-container"?